# Does Fontana di Trevi have a Latin name?

Tags: place-names, architecture

[Fontana di Trevi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trevi_Fountain) is a fountain in Rome, built in 1762.
Does it have a (trustworthy) Latin name?

The [Latin Wikipedia page](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontana_Trebii) uses the name *Fontana Trebii*, but no reference is given.
This name appears to be related to the Roman name [*Trebius*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=trebius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
However, I would expect an adjective (like *Trebiana*) instead of a genitive.

I imagine that the name of the fountain has something to do with the [Trevi district](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trevi_(rione_of_Rome)) of Rome.
The linked English Wikipedia page says (without references) that the name Trevi comes from the Latin *trivium*.
This is incompatible with the Latin name of the fountain mentioned above.

I would much appreciate it if there was a Latin document with the name of the fountain (or the district), but I have not been able to locate one.

Comment: I don't have the time to track this down now, but the etymology accepted by Pinto (referenced in the first wiki page) is that "Trevi" comes from "tre vie" (three roads). "Fons trivii" in quotes produces a few hits on Google, some of which are from older works; "Fons trium viarum" has one result from a Latin textbook that even includes a picture of the Trevi fountain!

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer here. The fountain was built in 1762, at a time where Italian was already in "[full use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language#Renaissance)" in Italy, including Rome. Without doubt the original name of the fountain was in Italian. As such, it is not surprising that Latin simply used the original name in Italian. For instance, [in this publication](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015082485585;view=1up;seq=272), in Latin, the name is written in Italian, signified by the emphasis. There are other similar examples in the text.

Sure, this does not mean it might not have been translated by someone, but my point is simply that its use in Italian might have been common even in Latin.

Comment: Actually, your linked text says very clearly that the Latin name is "Aqua Trivii".

Comment: @fdb Oh! Is that the bit that says "initio tamen, quando a "Summis Pontificibus" "Aqua Urbi" fuit restituta, "Tres Viae" fuerint, seu "Trivium", a quo "Aqua Trivii" et vulgo "di Trevi" appellata fuit"? But is this referring to the actual water of the fountain, or to the fountain itself?